# add values for custom attributes programtically

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-attributes

We are creating product programtically & inserting values for default attributes with help of below code.

how i can add values for **custom attributes** .

**attribute code : delivery_info , attribute label : Delivery & Return Info**

```
protected function _createProduct($type, $doSave=true, $originalProduct) 
    {

        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');       
        $product->setName($originalProduct->getName()); 
        $product->setDescription('what ever you need here')
                ->setPrice(599)
                ->setTaxClassId(0)    // Taxable Goods by default
                ->setWeight(1)
        ;                   

        if ($doSave)
            $product->save();

        return $product;
    }
```

Comment: is it dropdown Attribute ??

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala its `textfield` attribute.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like you do for any other attribute.

```
 $product->setDeliveryInfo('content goes here');
```

Just make sure the attribute exists in your database before doing that.

Comment: Before i tried `setDelivery_Info` Thanks , worked peRFectly today also as always:)

Answer (score 2):

As Marius suggested first one is magic method to set data

```
 $product->setDeliveryInfo('Your Data');
```

And second one is set data method

```
 $product->setData('delivery_info','Your data'); //key value pair
```

and save product and your job is done

> Above method will work only if it is a text ,textarea attribute for select and multiselect you need to pass attribute optionId in data